# Restrict comments in content type based on user role in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments, drupal-roles

I am building a site in Drupal, where there are 2 different types of registered users. Let us call them *basic users* and *premium users*. These could be roles or groups or something...

Authorized users will be able to publish pages with simple content and comments underneath. All pages are viewable publicly, even by non registered users and so are the comments.

Only registered users should be able to post comments.

What I would like is for some pages to allow comments only from *premium users*. So, there would be two categories of pages. Again let us call them *basic pages* and *premium pages*.

The permissions would be as follows:

**Basic pages**
READ: all
COMMENT: *basic users*, *premium users*

**Premium pages**
READ: all
COMMENT: *premium users*

Any help/pointers would be appreciated, as I have limited experience with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Is premium page different that basic page in terms of node type ?
Are you using panels to show the node and comments box ?
Are you using Drupal comments or third-party services (Disqus) ?

Comment: Not sure if that's an answer, but here goes: Different content type, no panels, but wouldn't mind, Drupal comments

Comment: Yeah, sure, I know! Just for fun, why don't you share a couple with us? :-)